# Azure Functions: Is it possible to subscribe to multiple topics?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics

This is my functions.json:

```
{
    "bindings": [
        {
            "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
            "name": "message",
            "connection": "ServiceBusConnectionString",
            "direction": "in",
            "topicName": "samples-topic",
            "subscriptionName": "samples",
            "accessRights": "manage"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to subscribe to more than one topic for the same function?

Cheers.

Comment: i don't think so. it does not hurt to create as many function apps you want to subscribe to multiple topics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple topics are not supported, but you can achieve the same results by creating subscriptions to forward messages from the topics you want to use, to a target topic you can use from your function.

Another option is to have multiple functions, but the first recommendation would require less maintenance.

Comment: First recommendation is indeed simpler to maintain. What I'd add to it is to stamp your messages based on subscription so that Function could easily determine what message you're handling.

Comment: The second option would completely screw with prioritization of feeds and could result in higher priority messages getting stuck behind lower priority messages. Unless your business case is non critical - options two is the only real valid option.