# Azure function ServiceBusTrigger for multiple topics and subscriptions in Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a problem to solve with the azure service bus, I have 3 topics: EntityCreated, EntityUpdated and EntityDeleted, the message that they are getting depends on the operation, but the thing is that for the consumer side, I'm thinking to get the messages with an azure function ServiceBusTrigger for each topic and subscription, I have one subscrption per topic but I may have another one shortly, so I'm not sure about how to handle this. I belive that I could try to set a ServiceBusTrigger for the 3 topics and subscription for the same azure function, but I'm not sure if this is possible. What approach do you suggest for this situation?
I also have to get from the message an entity to get and create the object with it to send it to an strapi endpoint, I can get like 8 diffrent entities in this message, one type of entity per message so one operation can have in the entity atributte different entity, serialized. I'm using C# and .Net 6.

```
 <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
 <AzureFunctionsVersion>V4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

Comment: Why can’t you have a single Topic with three Subscriptions. You can route the message to appropriate Subscription based on the status.

Comment: You cannot bind a single trigger to more than one Service Bus entity.   Maybe consider setting up forwarding rules so that anything arriving on these 3 topics is published to a single queue/topic for your function to process?    More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments @Jesse Squire and @Gaurav Mantri.
Since, it is not possible to connect multiple Service Bus entities to a single trigger.

- It is good to create different Trigger functions. I had referred the below Document for the source [code.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/127830/azure-function-with-service-bus-topic-trigger-to-r)

```cs
public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger(“entitycreated”, “balaji123”, Connection = “balaji”)\]string mySbMsg)  
{  
_logger.LogInformation($“C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}”);  
}
```

The message which I sent from the azure service bus is able to retrieve in service bus trigger.

[image]

Here is my **local.settings.json** file.
[image]

For more information and clarification refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949929/21518858) link.

- Refer this [document](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-send-read-messages-from-azure-service-bus-queues-using-azure/) for sending and reading the service bus messages.